# Ограничение браузера в прочтении файла application.py

Tags: python, sql, flask, условия

При написании кода для `application.py` столкнулся с тем, что в `if` не могу задать определенное условие. Связана данная проблема с тем, что я пытаюсь обратиться к несуществующему значению массива, выбранной мной из `SQL`.

Прилагаю код:

```
    creator = db.execute("SELECT username AS name FROM history WHERE added=:added", added=added)
    creator = creator[0]["name"]

    anName = db.execute("SELECT username FROM history WHERE idea=:idea AND added=:added AND username!=:username AND deleted=:deleted", idea=idea, added=added, username=name, deleted=deleted)

    yourName = db.execute("SELECT username FROM history WHERE idea=:idea AND type=:type AND files=:files AND description=:description AND user_id=:user_id AND username=:username AND added=:added AND deleted=:deleted", 
                idea=idea, type=type1, files=files, description=description, user_id=session["user_id"], username=name, added=added, deleted=deleted)

    if not anName and not yourName:
        ...
    elif anName != None:
        if anName[0]["username"] == creator:
            ...
    elif yourName != None:
        if yourName[0]["username"] == creator:
            ...
```

Как вы можете наблюдать, значения `anName` и `yourName` могут также быть `None`.

Соответственно, чтобы уберечь код от ошибки, я сначала ставил `anName != None`. В таком случае, браузер должен был пропустить `if`, условие в котором неверно. Однако, как я понял, браузер прочитывает условие даже внутри неверного `if` и при `anName == None`, а `yourName != None` все равно выдает ошибку

```
if yourName[0]["username"] == creator:
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

**Вопрос:** Могу ли я ограничить браузер от прочтения условий, значения в которых будут равны `None`?

Comment: `len()` никогда не бывает None

Comment: @andreymal Благодарю! Смотрел на сайте справки, однако не правильно понял теорию. Однако проблема осталась

Comment: сравнение с None никогда до добра не доводит

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась заменой `None` на `0` в проверке `if`. Благодарю @andreymal за идею!

```
    if not anName and not yourName:
        ...
    elif len(anName) != 0:
        if anName[0]["username"] == creator:
            ...
    elif len(yourName) != 0:
        if yourName[0]["username"] == creator:
            ...
```

Comment: или заменить просто `not len(anName)` и `not len(yourName)`

Comment: @Twiss Да, так тоже можно. Благодарю за идею! А в случае, если нужно проверить наличие `anName`, нужно писать `if not len(anName) == False`?

Comment: просто без `not` писать

Comment: @Twiss Благодарю!